Citrix published app asks for credentials
We use Citrix Virtual Apps & Desktops to publish applications to our users. One of our streamed applications can be started by the users and works well.
But: out of the application is the ability to open files in MS Word or MS Excel. If the user wants to open a Excel file for example out of the streamed application, Excel starts and asks for network credentials.
What I've figured out is, that this behaviour must be caused by a linked GPO. I've tested it by moving a shared Desktop to another OU without any GPOs, here the application is able to open XLS Files in Excel without asking for credentials.
Living without any GPOs is no option for security reasons - I'm pretty sure that there are no MS Office Settings in the GPOs. There are just settings for RDP License Servers and the behaviour for the Citrix Workspace App (Store URL, etc.) made. Has anybody an idea which GPO Setting could cause such a behaviour to Word and Excel?
Thank you!

You may want to specify if Word/Excel is also running as a published application.

Hi, Excel and Word are installed locally on the VirtualApp Server (not on the client that's starting the virtualapp)

There is three thing that need to be done to have that work with SSO.
First; The Receiver need to be installed with the Run As Admin command, with the PassThrought configuration. The option to select it would not be there if you run the setup with a admin account but if the run as was not used.
That one is probably done right, as changing the GPO work
Secondly; The StoreFront URI need to be inside the thrusted site.
There is the correct GPO to set it;

I know IE is no longer there, but the site need to be set with that option nonetheless.
This is the option you need to set:


Add the Storefront FQDN with its http/https protocol to the Trusted
sites as follows: Open up your Internet Explorer browser and go to
Tools > Internet Options. Then go to Security > Trusted Sites > Sites.

Reference
Thirdly; Not noted inside the CTX I referenced, but the certificate if homemade must be deployed to the computer too if using HTTPS (as you can still use HTTP store too, I dont know your case)

SSO is working fine. Just in this case, if one app opens word or excel are credentials needed.

@AndreasWinter Did you mean the Microsoft account credential that is needed ? if so, you need to install the office suite with machine activation to support like an O365 office on a remote server.

@AndreasWinter and if you mean if an xenapp's app try to open excel and it ask for an password, that mean the SSO prerequierement are not installed inside the xenapp server, as the server become the one to call the connection (aka client)
